# navigator.geolocation and cache problem with iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, caching, geolocation, coordinates

I've a website where users can do checkin, so their position will be sent to server that save it and show coords on google maps...

I'm testing it with my iphone and i noticed that when the webpage request position, the iphone activate gps to retrieve coords... Is that true? (obviously i did this using 3G and not WIFI)

Ok, it works well but i've noticed that coords had a big margin of error or are the same of the last checkin (but the place is not the same!)

So, i thought that my iphone cached somewhere the old coords of the last checkin... Is it possible?

How can i clear the cache with jquery/javascript before do checkin?
Why the error using gps is so big? (i've also specified a parameter that reduce the error!)

Thanks a lot!
Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Geolocation API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#api_description) has a number of options related to accuracy. Look at it.

You can specify the maximum age of the fix (the spec allows caching), how long you're willing to wait for the device to find itself, and whether you want the position to be "high accuracy" (it is *not* by default).

Comment: Yes, i specified the high accuracy but i don't know other options... Is there an option that prevent coords cache? Thanks!

Comment: So if i add the "maxiumim age" option to my getPosition call and i set it to a low value, i prevent old location cache? If true i solved! Let me know if someone know something about this... Thanks!

Comment: @Enricosoft Actually, the spec says that `maximumAge` is 0 by default — if you don't specify it, you should never get a cached result! However, it may be worth trying with `maximumAge` set to 0, just in case the iPhone doesn't follow the spec.

Comment: @Enricosoft Your "solution" is a broken link. If the solution wasn't one of the given answers, can you post it as your own answer? (Or, as an update to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Cell phone GPS' are notoriously inaccurate. I believe the iPhone uses GPS **and** triangulation to pinpoint your location, but it still does so with a very large margin of error.

To clear your Safari cache on the iPhone, launch the Settings app, select Safari, select Clear Cache.

Comment: I think Enricosoft means a cached location, which is separate from the browser's cache.

Comment: Really? Well, but app like google maps or others similar aren't inaccurate... Is different to get coords from web page or from apps? Yes, i mean cached location and not the browser cache... Exists a method to clear it? Thanks!

Comment: Well I have the 3GS, maybe the iPhone 4 is better. For me the Maps app often puts me on a road that's 100 ft or more away from the road that I'm actually on. I also think apps like Maps spend more time figuring out your location and averaging the data, so the longer it's there the more accurate it becomes.